# Zuul reverse Proxy gives 404 when forwarding the request to services after upgrading to Greenwich release

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I am using spring embedded Zuul proxy and eureka service registry in my microservice application.
After upgrading the spring cloud dependencies to Greenwich it gives 404 error in zuul gateway level.

Following are my configurations.

Zuul Gateway Main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableZuulProxy
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableHystrixDashboard
@EnableHystrix
public class GatewayApplication {
}
```

application.yml

```
zuul:
    ignoreSecurityHeaders: false
    sensitiveHeaders:
routes:
    oauth:
      path: /oauth/**
      serviceId: oauth-server
    payment:
      path: /payment/**
      serviceId: payment-service

eureka:
   client:
      serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8082/eureka/
      registerWithEureka: true

spring:
   application:
      name: zuul-gateway
```

Payment service main class

```
@SpringBootApplication()
@EnableJpaRepositories({ "com.payment.repo" })
@EntityScan("com.payment.domain")
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableSwagger2
public class PaymentServiceApplication {}
```

application.yml

```
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8082/eureka/
    registerWithEureka: true

spring:
  application:
    name: payment-service
```

I was able to forward requests successfully to services from zuul proxy with Finchley.RELEASE. Following are the previous maven dependencies.

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>


 <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Finchley.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.zipkin.brave</groupId>
                <artifactId>brave-bom</artifactId>
                <version>5.4.3</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
 </dependencyManagement>
```

After upgrading spring cloud dependencies to Greenwich.release I'm unable to forward requests to services from zuul proxy. It's giving 404.

Because when call payment-service in zuul previously URL shows as

```
http://localhost:8181/payment/v1/fundTransfer/test
```

Now it shows as

```
http://localhost:8181/v1/fundTransfer/test
```

It seems zuul is not adding the path value (payment).  If I revert back to Finchley It's working fine with same configurations.

Do I need to change any routing configuration in application.yml of zuul proxy?

Comment: Did you update spring boot to 2.1.x.RELEASE as well?

Comment: Yes. updated to 2.1.2.RELEASE .

Comment: can you try adding `stripPrefix: false` below `serviceId`?